# Is there a way to get the other currencies without online play?

Tags: 100-orange-juice

I started playing *100% Orange Juice* and in the store i see 3 Currencies along with Stars

- Oranges
- Candy (seems to be for Halloween items)
- Christmas Holly (doesn't show up with Stars, Oranges or Candy, only see it with Christmas Items)

with the first one the in-game guide says i got to play online to get them and i don't know how to get the others.

as someone who prefers playing offline single player, is there a way to get the other currencies without online play?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get all of them in single player except for the oranges as these come from multiplayer "daily" tasks. I'm not sure about every individual currency (past and future) but no need to worry. You can create a password-protected multiplayer lobby then start the game alone, effectively playing single-player with 3 CPUs and having access to all of the "online" events.